# Vitest: Mock a provider's custom useContext in a consumer component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, vite, vitest

**The premise**

I have the following components:

```
// providers/SomeContextProvider.tsx

import { createContext, ReactNode, useContext } from 'react';

const SomeContext = createContext('');

export type Props = {
  children: ReactNode;
};
export default function SomeContextProvider(props: Props) {
  const [someCalculatedValue, setSomeCalculatedValue] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    //calculate and set the someCalculatedValue
  }, [])

  return (
    <SomeContext.Provider value={someCalculatedValue}>
      {props.children}
    </SomeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useSomeContext() {
  return useContext(SomeContext);
}
```

```
// SomeConsumer.tsx

import { useSomeContext } from 'providers/SomeContextProvider'

return function SomeConsumer() {
  const contextValue = useSomeContext();

  return (/***/);
}
```

I want to test `SomeConsumer` in a way that I can control the "computed value" that it gets from `useSomeContext()`.

In order to do that I am mocking the `SomeContextProvider.tsx` file by creating a `providers/__mocks__/SomeContextProvider.tsx` (as per [Vitest docs](https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-mock))

```
//providers/__mocks__/SomeContextProvider.tsx

import { createContext, ReactNode, useContext } from 'react';

const SomeContext = createContext('');

export type Props = {
  children: ReactNode;
  testValue: string; // Notice the mock provider accepts the value that it will pass down, as a prop
};
export default function SomeContextProvider(props: Props) {
  return (
    <SomeContext.Provider value={props.testValue}>
      {props.children}
    </SomeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useSomeContext() {
  return useContext(SomeContext);
}
```

and then mocking the module in the test file:

```
// SomeConsumer.test.tsx

import SomeConsumer from 'SomeConsumer.tsx';
import SomeContextProvider from 'providers/SomeContextProvider'
import { customRender } from 'test/utils';

vi.mock('providers/SomeContextProvider');

describe('SomeConsumer', function () {
  it('should match snapshot', () => {
    const { asFragment } = customRender(
      <SomeContextProvider testValue={'someValue}>
        <SomeConsumer>{/***/}</SomeConsumer>
      </SomeContextProvider>
    );

    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

**The problem**

The problem is that while the mocked `SomeContextProvider` is indeed called, can confirm this by setting breakpoints, `SomeConsumer` is still calling the `useSomeContext` exported from the original `providers/SomeContextProvider.tsx` and not the one exported from `providers/__mocks__/SomeContextProvider.tsx` and as a result this is not working as intended.

**The question**

How can I make it so that when testing `SomeConsumer` it is using the mocked `useSomeContext` that is exported from the mocked `SomeContextProvider.tsx` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, nevermind, this seems to work fine after all. Turns out I had forgotten a `doMock` instead of `mock` there, while I was testing this. All's well